# Automating cf login refresh

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-cli

Does the CloudFoundry UAA support token refresh for logged in user.
I'm currently logged in using the "cf-cli" via the SSO passcode. After a week or so the session expires and I have to log in again.
Is it possible to refresh the token in the $HOME/.cf/config.json upon expiry ?
As per this https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6 , we should be able to refresh the token by passing
grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA options.
However, it expects the client_id or client_secret to be present i.e use BASIC Auth.
Can we do with a currently logged in user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refresh an access token, but you cannot refresh a refresh token. When your refresh token expires, you must login again.

The `refresh_token` from `config.json` is a JWT token, so you can use a tool like https://jwt.io to view the token and see when it expires. Your refresh token *will* expire at some point, it just depends on how long your administrator allows it to last. A week sounds pretty standard.

Hope that helps!